# How can i format my data like this in table

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I have a dynamic data where they have the same floornumber, so i wanna do is every data have a same number will be under a row on their floor. I want to make every row theirs a row, and then under all of that is their units. Is their any library for that? Thanks

```
const data = [
{floornumber: 1, unitname: '101', unitype: 'basic'},
{floornumber: 1, unitname: '102', unitype: 'basic'},
{floornumber: 1, unitname: '103', unitype: 'basic'},
{floornumber: 2, unitname: '203', unitype: 'basic'},
{floornumber: 2, unitname: '203', unitype: 'basic'}

]
<table>  
<thead>
    <th>
      Floor
    </th>
    <th>
      Unit Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Unit Type
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blank</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>Basic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blank</td>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>Basic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blank</td>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>Basic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blank</td>
      <td>203</td>
      <td>Basic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blank</td>
      <td>203</td>
      <td>Basic</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a library for this because it is a very unique way to present the data.
You must make sure, your data is sorted by floor number. Then I would read the first line and create row set a:

```
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>blank</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>Basic</td>
    </tr>
```

loop through your data and create row set b:

```
    <tr>
      <td>blank</td>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>Basic</td>
    </tr>
```

until the floor number changes. In this case create row set a again and so on until you are at the end of the data.